# Three-sphere as a sphere bundle over circle

Tags: low-dimensional-topology, hopf-fibration

When we view $S^3$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ through the equation $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1$, the Hopf fibration $S^1\to S^3\xrightarrow{p} S^2$ is usually given by (see, e.g., Wikipedia)
$$
p(z_1,z_2)=(z_1z_2^*,|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2).
$$
The Hopf fiber can be identified with the $U(1)$ acting as
$$
(z_1,z_2)\to (e^{i\phi}z_1,e^{i\phi}z_2).
$$
I am interested in considering a different $U(1)$ which is generated by
$$
(z_1,z_2)\to (e^{in\phi}z_1,e^{i\tilde{n}\phi}z_2)
$$
for $n,\tilde{n}\in \mathbb{Z}$ general. When $\tilde{n}=n$ this reduces to the usual Hopf fiber, but in general now the base $S^2$ rotates as one moves along the associated fiber.
Therefore, this version of $S^3$ is not anymore a fiber bundle in the sense that locally it is not described by a product of $S^2\times S^1$.

Is it correct to view this version of $S^3$ rather as an $S^2$ bundle over $S^1$? Any other perspective of this geometry would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting spaces are known as [lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space).  These are an important source of counterexamples in low-dimensional topology.  The homeomorphism classification is more subtle, and is given by [Reidemeister torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_torsion).  Similar constructions are possible on  all odd-dimensional spheres.

Comment: @sam, No, if you use the scalar action you get the simplest lens spaces which are actually homogeneous spaces.  Not all of them are.

Comment: I see. For the action I defined, what would be the value of the usual $(p,q)$ numbers that label a lens space? And am I correctly understanding that the ones I define would not be homogeneous?